# How can I use a custom layout between the ActionBar and the Tabs?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I want to have a custom piece of layout between my ActionBar and the Tabs. Is there any way to do this? Maybe a custom view in the ActionBar, or split tabs?

This custom part possibly means I have to adjust the height of the actionbar. I wasn't able to do that either.

So is there a way to get the app working like I designed?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE9m7.png)

Comment: You would simply use the standard TabHost instead of ActionBar tabs placing the extra content between the actual ActionBar and the TabHost.

Comment: Since TabHost is deprecated I assumed there would be another solution

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated, TabHost is not.